# Protect Specific Services on Client PC

Tags: windows, service-account

I am not sure if I am asking in the correct location for this, but will ask in the hopes you assist. I want to be able to lock certain services from being restarted/stopped/ended. I know most Anti-Virus and Firewall Clients protect their own services from being touched, I would assume there some component of the application that prevents itself from being altered, such as real time protector.

I have done some looking around and know I can run the service controller from command line as follows:

```
sc <server> [command] [service name] <option1> <option2>...
```

So I had a quick look around for the Server Control Manager and I believe it a snap-in of mmc. I have had a look into the help of sc within comand prompt as I want to generate a list of services I can prevent from being tampered with. I have the same problem here - [Our users are Admins and are required to be able to start and stop specific services](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2758d69a-60e8-4a5b-83dd-fc7d8e15bdc1/preventing-users-from-stopping-a-particular-service-with-a-gpo?forum=winserverGP).

For Computers not on the domain however I would need to set local GPO. I want to be able to run a small startup script to run sc and lock several services from being tampered with. I had a look on the Support Microsoft (/kb/251192) and cannot see any clear guide to blacklist one being protected.

Is this achievable?

Comment: You want to protect these services against tampering by local admins I'm guessing?

Comment: @NeilSmithline Well our Domain Users are Admins, but also for the misuse of admin accounts.